# Notepad++ fails to find backslash when preceded by a colon

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of paths in which I need to replace every backslash with a slash:

```
C:\Users\Temp\Desktop\file1
C:\Users\Temp\Desktop\file2
C:\Users\Temp\Desktop\file3
...
```

For some reason, Notepad++ does not find the first backslash in every line.

I verified that this problem is due to the preceding colon (by removing it).

How can I "convince" Notepad++ not to ignore that backslash without this "hack"?

Comment: Works for me. How do you search it?

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce your problem: it appeared when I enabled the "Match whole word only" option.

If you have this option turned on try switching it off:

[image]

Comment: Nice! It's equivalent to search with wordboundaries.